# how to check whether outlook is install in system or not using java?

Tags: java, outlook

hello i am searching about is outlook installed in system or not? i am working in Java. i have found few link but i cant reach at my goal.i found one method 
 "Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");", but i dont know  which  package i should import.
i write following code but it gives me error.

```
  Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");

 if (officeType == null)
 {
   // Outlook is not installed.   
  // Show message or alert that Outlook is not installed.
 }
else
{
    // Outlook is installed.    
    // Continue your work.
}
```

help to solve this issue. thanks in advance...

Comment: The first result for googling "GetTypeFromProgID" is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type.gettypefromprogid. You will have some trouble using *that* method in java.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin is it possible using java?

Answer (score 2):

Every software creates an entry into the Windows registry during installation. In order to find out if any software in installed or not, you need to scan and search registries in Windows machine. There's a 3rd party Java API with which you can access the Windows registry: [jRegistryKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregistrykey/).

Sample program:

```
package your.pkg;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;

import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RootKey;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        RegistryKey.initialize(Test.class.getResource("jRegistryKey.dll").getFile());
        RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKLM, "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\<version>\\Outlook\\");
        for (Iterator<RegistryKey> subkeys = key.subkeys(); subkeys.hasNext();) {
            RegistryKey subkey = subkeys.next();
            System.out.println(subkey.getName()); // You need to check here if there's anything which matches "Mozilla FireFox".
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i am using Ubuntu os.. is it possible?

Comment: Not sure about how to do it on Ubuntu. Will figure out and update the answer soon.

Comment: should i download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregistrykey/postdownload?source=dlp?

Comment: i have download it and i am trying code which you given by you. will it check whether outlook is installed or not?

Comment: Yes. It will check for Outlook software registry in present or not in windows machine. Just cross check the registry key string for outlook. One which is provided here is based on Windows XP (.. I know it's pretty older Windows *sigh*).